# docker: cannot map "/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock"?

Tags: mysql, docker, dockerfile

I try to access mysql server running on host from docker container via socket mapping.

This is what Dockerfile looks like.

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

ENV container docker
ENV init /lib/systemd/systemd

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y  \
      apache2           \
      curl              \
      mysql-client      \
      net-tools         \
      python3           \
      vim               \
      wget

VOLUME [ "/sys/fs/cgroup" ]
ENTRYPOINT ["/lib/systemd/systemd"]
```

This is how I start docker container.

```
docker run --privileged -d -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro -v /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock:/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock -it ubn
```

I check that mysql server runs ok on host machine and /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock does exist. However, it doesn't exist on docker container which indicates mapping is not successful. Which could go wrong? Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Can you tell which system your host is? Are you running on Linux or Mac? Using Docker for Mac or something like VirtualBox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get this question answered from Docker community, basically it cannot use systemd along with mapping mysqld.sock. I don't have any deep explanation beyond that.